# BeautifulSoup not defined when called in function

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My web scraper is throwing `NameError: name 'BeautifulSoup' is not defined` when I call BeautifulSoup() inside my function, but it works normally when I call it outside the function and pass the Soup as an argument.

Here is the working code:

```
from teams.models import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from django.conf import settings
import requests, os, string

soup = BeautifulSoup(open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'revolver.html')), 'html.parser')

def scrapeTeamPage(soup):
    teamInfo = soup.find('div', 'profile_info')
...
print(scrapeTeamPage(soup))
```

But when I move the BeautifulSoup call inside my function, I get the error.

```
from teams.models import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from django.conf import settings
import requests, os, string

def scrapeTeamPage(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, url)), 'html.parser')
    teamInfo = soup.find('div', 'profile_info')
```

Comment: Isn't it saying `Name url not defined`? Because it's not defined in your second example.

Comment: edited to reflect my code

Comment: Did you really copy the samples from your code? If not, check for spelling errors (e.g. try case-sensitive search)

Comment: Please include the complete error message.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are doing some spelling mistake of BeautifulSoup, its case sensitive. if not, use requests in your code as:

```
from teams.models import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from django.conf import settings
import requests, os, string

def scrapeTeamPage(url):
    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
    teamInfo = soup.find('div', 'profile_info')
```

Answer (score 0):

Import BeautifulSoup first into a variable and then use it.

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as yourVariable
```

Comment: please do not post only code , Add a description for more help